# How to print comma seperated output?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 200)
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)

preds=le.inverse_transform(y_pred)
datatocsv=pd.DataFrame({'id':range(1,len(preds)+1),'taste':preds})
datatocsv.to_csv('prediction.csv',index=False)
```

Suppose I  have saved the prediction output in a csv file named prediction.csv
and this csv file has two columns 'id' and 'taste' column

[image: output_format image]

But I want to print the prediction output in the format specified in the image.
Please guide

Answer (score 0):

```
X = pd.DataFrame(['taste', 'good', 'normal'])
X

Out[12]: 
        0
0   taste
1    good
2  normal


X.to_csv('predicition.csv', sep=',')

datatocsv.to_csv('prediction.csv')
```

This leads to:

[image]

Comment: Tried above code but output is not coming in desired format as shown in image

Comment: did you try the above code and it still didnt work? I will check the notebook later that day .

Comment: what was your error? If my answer was at lest usefull to you I wouls appreciate that you accept and upvote the answe so that others can find the solution too. Greetings